# DHX Scheduler undefined

Tags: typescript, vue.js, undefined, scheduler, vuejs3

I'm starting to use VueJs 3 with TS and composition api.

I found this [tutorial](https://dhtmlx.com/blog/use-dhtmlx-scheduler-vue-js-framework-demo/#comment-4967138751) about how to import the scheduler in VueJs.

Unfortunately it doesn't cover completely my case and therefore I'm finding some troubles.

In the specific, I'm facing this error:

> scheduler is not defined

In the comments they propose to use:

```
/*global scheduler*/
import 'dhtmlx-scheduler'
```

but then it doesn't find the scheduler anymore:

> TS2304: Cannot find name 'scheduler'.

The IDE proposes me to import it like this:

```
import { scheduler } from 'dhtmlx-scheduler'
```

But, even in this case, the scheduler is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `dhtmlx-scheduler` with TypeScript, make sure to import `dhtmlx-scheduler` in addition to the `SchedulerStatic` type:

```js
import 'dhtmlx-scheduler'
import { SchedulerStatic } from 'dhtmlx-scheduler'
```

Then you could use `window.scheduler` like this:

```js
const scheduler: SchedulerStatic = (window as any).scheduler
scheduler.init(/*...*)
```

*Example of TypeScript SFC based on [docs](https://dhtmlx.com/blog/use-dhtmlx-scheduler-vue-js-framework-demo/)*:

```html
<template>
  <div ref="scheduler"></div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import 'dhtmlx-scheduler'
import { SchedulerStatic } from 'dhtmlx-scheduler'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'scheduler',
  props: {
    events: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const scheduler: SchedulerStatic = (window as any).scheduler // eslint-disable-line
    scheduler.skin = 'material'
    scheduler.config.header = [
        'day',
        'week',
        'month',
        'date',
        'prev',
        'today',
        'next'
    ]

    scheduler.init(this.$refs.scheduler as HTMLElement, new Date(2020, 0, 20), 'week')
    scheduler.parse(this.$props.events)
  }
})
</script>

<style>
@import "~dhtmlx-scheduler/codebase/dhtmlxscheduler_material.css";
</style>
```